# How can iconify achieve ondemand icon usage in Vue Vite 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vite

In the iconify documentation: https://iconify.design/docs/api/

There is only one thing to do:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @iconify/vue
```

```js
import { Icon } from '@iconify/vue';
```

```html
<Icon icon="mdi-light:home" />
```

And then it will bundle only used icon, how can it achieve this feature?

Because there is no additional build config.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't get it. What is the problem?

Comment: defining the icon on the icon property already achieves the on-demand icon feature of Iconify (being handled under the hood). What is the issue? Can you explain further?

Comment: it uses the concept of pure css icons, learn more about it here https://antfu.me/posts/icons-in-pure-css

Comment: I want to know why it just works because I don't need to modify vite.config.js and it automatically bundle only used icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fetching the icon data at first load, after that, it cached the api response at localstorage.